# Binary search tree String search

Tags: java, binary-tree

I have a program where I need to search for a specific word in a binary tree, the code I came up with for the search method for the string is not working. if someone could take a look at it I would greatly appreciate it.

I have tried a few alterations to this but it still did not work.

```
public boolean check(BSTNode t,String key){
    if(!t.word.equals(key)){
        check(t.left,key);
        check(t.right,key);
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I have edited your tags. Please make sure to choose tags that match the problem, not just words that appear in your question. For example, the [tag:binary] tag has nothing to do with binary trees. This helps get your question in front of people who can answer it. I also added the [tag:java] tag, since I believe you are working in Java. Now Stack Overflow can syntax highlight your code correctly. If this is the wrong language please change it.

Answer (score 2):

This could be written like this;

```
public boolean check(BSTNode t,String key) {
    return 
      t.word.equals(key) || check(t.left,key) || check(t.right,key)
}
```

or, more verbosely;

```
public boolean check(BSTNode t,String key) {
    if (t.word.equals(key)) return true;

    if (check(t.left,key)) return true;

    if (check(t.right,key)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

You don't need a lot of `else` statements because the `return` statements stop execution in the function.

**Edit:**

You must also check to see that your BSTNode is not null, or you will get null pointer exceptions when you reach the end of the tree. This could be done at the start of the function, or before the inner recursive `check` calls:

```
public boolean check(BSTNode t,String key) {

    if (t == null) return false;

    if (t.word.equals(key)) return true;

    if (check(t.left,key)) return true;

    if (check(t.right,key)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

or;

```
public boolean check(BSTNode t,String key) {
    if (t.word.equals(key)) return true;

    if (t.left != null && check(t.left,key)) return true;

    if (t.right != null && check(t.right,key)) return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for taking your time to look at my code, i really appreciate it.

Comment: You bet. Let me know if you have any questions.